# Loop through String array to fill it with input from user

Tags: java

just a another noob to Java with a dumb question.
I am trying to create a function that receives a String array and fills it with text input from the user using Bufferedreader (which I currently want to use).
I sort of have the idea in my head but it gives the error `cannot find symbol` when using the `readline()` property. How can I achieve this?

```
public static BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

public static void fill_array (String parray []){

        for(int i = 0; i < parray.length; i++){
            parray[i] = in.readline(); //Here it gives me the error
        }
    }
```

Comment: It must be `readLine()` and not `readline()`

Comment: @user7 no way! xD thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`readLine()` and not `readline` how embarrasing

Comment: @Rich umm, it answers the question exactly? Could have been worded better but put some effort into the reviews.

Comment: Though, to be fair, such a question should be closed for being caused by a typo, rather than answered

Answer (score 1):

Hii Scanner is much more simpler than BufferedReader to read input, Let me give you an example :

```js
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
  public static void main(String arp[])
  {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String address = scanner.nextLine(); // read string with spaces
    System.out.println("addres : "+ address);
    String name = scanner.next(); // read string without spaces
    System.out.println("name : "+ name);
    Integer age = scanner.nextInt();  // read Integer input
    System.out.println("age : "+ age);
  }
}
```

Scanner java api link : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html